# How are weapons enhanced by multiple Spirit cubes?

Tags: cube-world

Like other smelted cubes, [Spirit](http://cubeworldwiki.net/index.php/Spirit) can modify your weapons to add additional effects to your special attacks.

When adding multiple Spirit cubes, do the effects increase with the number of Spirit cubes? Can different kinds of Spirit cubes be mixed to provide multiple additional effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put as many spirit cubes on your weapon up to the customization limit (so be careful about loading up on simple cubes).

all of the spirits can be put on a weapon and all effects will be achieved. You can have a fire ice weapon that deals extra damage and slows.

You can only put spirits of the power level or slightly lower.

With 1 unholy spirit cube on my crossbow, I got additional .1HP back per hit every 20th combo (so 200 combo is 1hp per hit). With 2, this effect doubled. I havent been able to test more because usable spirit cubes are a bit rare.

http://www.cubeworldwiki.net/index.php/Spirit

Comment: AFAIK you can remove cubes from weapon customization, so loading up on simple cubes is something you'd want to do until you get better cubes. Otherwise, very informative answer, all the +1s!